# Controller class xxxController could not be found error

Tags: iis, cakephp

I was migrating my web application to another server.  Everything works fine except for viewing any uploaded file. It keeps showing the same error whenever I tried to view the uploaded file.

[image]

**Updated :**

eland\app\webroot\upload
`Not Working --> <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('<i class="icon-file"></i>'), '../'.ELAND.'/upload/'.trim($rec['Bahanrujukan']['filename']), array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-small','target'=>'_blank', 'escape' => false)); ?>`

eland\app\webroot\img\imgs
`Working --> <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('<i class="icon-file"></i>'), '../'.ELAND.'/img/imgs/'.trim($rec['Bahanrujukan']['filename']), array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-small','target'=>'_blank', 'escape' => false)); ?>`

Should I check the plugin or the controller?

Comment: IIS .htaccess handling is not 100% compatible with Apache's, as I recall.

Comment: As the error message says, please check if xxxController exists in your project.  and is the URL you requested is correct?

Comment: Hi @samwu, that xxx is filename hence I dont think it should be the controller.

Comment: You can use the IIS Microsoft Management Console snap-in to determine where the file requested must exist in the IIS computer's file system and please verify that the file requested in the browser's URL exists on the IIS computer and that it is in the correct location.

Comment: Why are you including `'../'.ELAND.` at the start of your links? Why not just "/upload/..." and "/img/imgs/..."? If your server is correctly configured to point at the webroot folder, then this should be all you need.

Comment: Unrelated, why are you trying to translate `<i class="icon-file"></i>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, the issue was misconfiguration in web.config. During translation from Apache (.htaccess) to IIS (web.config), the 'upload' folder was not granted for access to the webroot. 
`<rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^(img|css|files|js|upload|favicon.ico)(.*)$" /> <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" /></rule>`
thanks guys for helping me out!